# how to find date difference when dates are places in different rows in same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, logic

I have a table::

```
ItemID  VersionNo  CreatedDate
-------------------------------
1       3          7/9/2010
1       2          7/3/2010
1       1          5/3/2010
1       0          3/3/2010
2       0          4/4/2010
3       1          4/5/2010
3       0          3/4/2010
```

...where Version 0 means .. its a newly produced item. Here I need to find time,(time gap between two versions) and add a column as process time.
like::

```
ItemID  VersionNo  CreatedDate  ProcessTime
-------------------------------------------
1       3          7/9/2010     6Days or 6*24Hrs
1       2          7/3/2010     60Days 
1       1          5/3/2010     2Days
1       0          3/3/2010     ''
2       0          4/4/2010     '' 
3       1          4/5/2010     31Days
3       0          3/4/2010     ''
```

VersionNo's are not Fixed..means with time, it could  increase... How to acheive the desire result in MS Access or in SQL-Server.

Thanks in advance for all your sincere efforts.
Thanks

Comment: Another case where LEAD/LAG would've made this easy... The `createddate` - is it a DATETIME, DATE, or VARCHAR?

Comment: We could keep it as a varchar, as we need this information for display purpose....

Comment: That's a presentation issue, easily dealt with using [CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Can there be any gaps in VersionNo, or does (v.ItemID = vPrior.ItemID AND v.VersionNo = vPrior.VersionNo + 1) always match the current to the prior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about (Access):

```
SELECT t.ItemID, 
       t.VersionNo, 
       t.CreatedDate, (
          SELECT Top 1 
          CreatedDate 
          FROM Versions v 
          WHERE v.ItemID=t.ItemID 
          And v.VersionNo<t.VersionNo 
          ORDER BY VersionNo DESC) AS LastDate, 
       DateDiff("h",[LastDate],[CreatedDate]) AS DiffHrs,
       DateDiff("d",[LastDate],[CreatedDate]) AS DiffDays
FROM Versions t
```

Answer (score 2):

Join the table with itself, like this (SQL Server):

```
-- create the table and your data
create table #x (ItemID int, VersionNo int, CreatedDate datetime)
go
insert into #x
select 1,       3          ,'7/9/2010'
union all select  1       ,2          ,'7/3/2010'
union all select  1       ,1          ,'5/3/2010'
union all select  1       ,0          ,'3/3/2010'
union all select  2       ,0          ,'4/4/2010'
union all select  3       ,1          ,'4/5/2010'
union all select  3       ,0          ,'3/4/2010'
go

-- The query
select v2.ItemID, v2.VersionNo, datediff(dd, v1.CreatedDate, v2.CreatedDate)
from #x v1, #x v2
where v1.ItemID = v2.ItemID and v1.VersionNo + 1 = v2.VersionNo
```

Comment: This query won't include the version 0 records - you need an outer join to V1.

Comment: /* using outer join */

select v1.ItemID, v1.VersionNo, datediff(day, vPrior.CreatedDate, v1.CreatedDate)
from #T v1
left outer join #T vPrior
on v1.ItemID = vPrior.ItemID and v1.VersionNo - 1 = vPrior.VersionNo
order by v1.ItemID, v1.VersionNo desc

Comment: And, of course, the OUTER JOIN applies only to SQL Server, not to Jet/ACE.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in Access SQL, using 3 queries, one for each step.

Query1, self-join on itemID where versionNo is smaller:

```
    SELECT t1.itemID, t1.versionNo, t1.created, t2.versionNo AS t2Version
FROM Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN Table1 AS t2 ON t1.itemID = t2.itemID
WHERE (t2.versionNo)<[t1].[versionNo];
```

Query2, limit to max of smaller versionNos:

```
    SELECT q1.itemID, q1.versionNo, q1.created, Max(q1.t2Version) AS MaxOft2Version
FROM Query1 AS q1
GROUP BY q1.itemID, q1.versionNo, q1.created;
```

Query3, now do datediff:

```
SELECT q2.itemID, q2.versionNo, q2.created, q2.MaxOft2Version, t1.created, 
    DateDiff("d",[t1].[created],[Q2].[created]) AS daysdiff
FROM Query2 AS q2 INNER JOIN Table1 AS t1 
    ON (q2.MaxOft2Version = t1.versionNo) 
    AND (q2.itemID = t1.itemID);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005, to handle the case where there are gaps in VersionNo.

```
-- Declare a query that extends your table with a new column 
-- that is the sequentially numbered representation of VersionNo.
-- This could be a view, but I used a CTE.  I am going to use this
-- query twice below.
WITH Sequential AS (select *, 
    RANK() over (partition by ItemId order by VersionNo) as SequentialVersionNo
from #T as x
)
select 
    v.ItemID, v.VersionNo, v.SequentialVersionNo, v.CreatedDate, 
    DATEDIFF(day, vPrior.CreatedDate, v.CreatedDate) as ProcessTime
from Sequential as v
left outer join Sequential as vPrior 
on v.ItemID=vPrior.ItemID 
and v.SequentialVersionNo = vPrior.SequentialVersionNo+1;
```